# How to copy a folder whilst excluding some sub folders in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am very new to PowerShell and i am trying to copy a folder without some sub folders to a different folder. I have included my code below. Hope this makes sense.

```
$from = 'C:\erp\github\bliss_'
$to = 'C:\erp\websites\bitesize'
$ExcludeFolders = @(".git","DHTMLX","mflasite","nbproject",".gitignore")

Get-ChildItem -Path $from -Recurse -Exclude $ExcludeFolders |  Copy-Item  $_.fullname -Destination $from -Force -Exclude $ExcludeFolders
```

Comment: Use `robocopy`.

Answer (score 0):

So `-Exclude` qualifies the `Path`.  You need to enter a pattern that it can identify:

```
$ExcludeFolders = @(
    '*\.git\*'
    '*\DHTMLX\*'
    '*\mflasite\*'
    '*\nbproject\*'
    '*\.gitignore'
)
```

---

```
-Exclude <String[]>
    Specifies, as a string array, an item or items that this cmdlet excludes in
    the operation. The value of this parameter qualifies the Path parameter. Enter
    a path element or pattern, such as *.txt. Wildcards are permitted.

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                None
    Accept pipeline input?       False
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

Comment: I tend to avoid the `-Exclude` parameter because it's rather badly behaved.  Compare `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Windows\ -Exclude *.exe`, `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Windows\ -Exclude *.exe -File`, `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath C:\Windows\ -Exclude *.exe` and `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Windows\*.* -Exclude *.exe -File`.

Comment: @BaconBits In the documentation, `Exclude`/`Include` are only effective with a wildcard path or the `-Recurse` switch.  If you're in either of those situations, that's the right choice.  Otherwise using `Where-Object` is significantly slower.

Comment: Oh, you can figure out the behavior.  The problem is that it doesn't enforce it's own restrictions and it's *not obvious* that you're doing something wrong.  I'm not checking the documentation every time I need `ls -I`.  The fact that the command silently executes with *undefined* behavior and doesn't error when it gets incompatible parameters is a problem.  Yes, the problem is that `Get-ChildItem` was written prior to the concept of parameter sets.  It's still a major usability problem.

Comment: @BaconBits Any clue if someone has fixed it in 6.0? ;)

Comment: Not as far as I know.  There's a number of [similar or related issues](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+get-childitem+exclude) but nothing stands out to a cursory overview.  There are similar problems with the [`-Include` parameter](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+get-childitem+include+), too.  I've been meaning to install the v6 RC again, write up a good error report, and submit it as a change to implement parameter sets for `Get-ChildItem`, but haven't yet had the time.

Comment: @BaconBits Yeah, `-Include` is a lot more buggy.  It doesn't work without the * or `-Recurse` and if you do * without `-Recurse`, it'll change your query to `-Recurse -Depth 1`